# About Leinster's discussion of Corollary 4.3.10

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor

Corollary 4.3.10 in [Leinster's text](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) says that $H_A\cong H_{A'}\iff A\cong A'\iff H^A\cong H^{A'}$.

He writes: "the corollary tells us that two objects are the
same if and only if they look the same from all viewpoints (Figure 4.2)". But from what I understand, "looking the same from all viewpoints" only means that $H_A(B)\cong H_{A'}(B)$ for all $B$, and it doesn't subsume naturality. Is this correct?

On a similar note, he writes "For a general category, Corollary 4.3.10 tells us that two objects are the same
if they have the same generalized elements of all shapes." But again, having the same generalized elements of all shapes doesn't subsume naturality, from what I can tell...

[image]

Then he gives this example:

[image]

In each of these three sub-examples he doesn't assume that $H_A(B)\cong H_{A'}(B)$ for all $B$, nor does he assume naturality.  So are the conclusions of these sub-examples not related to the corollary? For example, does the conclusion "$A$ and $A'$ have isomorphic underlying sets" in the second sub-example come from a separate "lemma" about the existence of a bijection between  $H_A(\mathbb Z)$ and $A$?

And similarly, in the example below, I suppose he is not using Corollary 4.3.10; he seems to be using just our knowledge about sets, right?

[image]

Comment: I suppose naturality is tacit. Unnatural isomorphisms usually have no useful consequences.

Comment: I think this is a good question. I don't think I can formulate a great answer right now (I'll think about it), but my intuition is that the right notion of "looking the same from all viewpoints" *should* include naturality. If the hom-sets are merely isomorphic it just means the number of morphisms from B to A is the same as the number of morphisms from B to A' for every B. If they're naturally isomorphic it means you don't just have the same number of morphisms but they also behave in the same way, in a suitable sense. A good answer should be able to make that really intuitively clear.